# How to do recursion on distinct values in Teradata

Tags: recursion, teradata

Recursive queries in Teradata do not allow to use DISTINCT in the recursion itself as well as any AGG functions/ subqueries.

Is there any trick how to handle duplicated relationship during doing a recursion?

Comment: Only `union all` is allowed, but in most cases recursion can be replaced by something else. Can you add more details what you actually want to do?

Comment: A query can have non-recursive CTEs (to do a DISTINCT or other sorts of aggregation / subqueries) in addition to one RECURSIVE CTE. An example with sample data / desired output would help someone give a more complete answer.